# Custom Action Bar not taking all space of the action bar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

while creating a custom action bar in a application in android studio

the custom action bar was looking smaller than the usual action bar

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6354B0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/todo"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">


            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/organize_your_day_with_tasks"
                android:textSize="16sp">


            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

java code for action bar

```
val actionBar = supportActionBar
actionBar?.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
actionBar?.setCustomView(R.layout.todo_action_bar)

actionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
actionBar?.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)
```

suggest something for this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Gv0.jpg)

the above code shows this

I have tried many solution on the web, but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

You need update Parent `RelativeLayout`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

And Top `LinearLayout`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

the new xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#6354B0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/todo"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">


            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/organize_your_day_with_tasks"
                android:textSize="16sp">


            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```